# no match for 'operator=' when searching for value in map

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator, maps, operators

I'm a c++ noob and I can't figure this one out. I'm trying to search for a value in a map using the module parameter as a key as seen below. The first error I get is a no match for operator equals on the line indicated below and the second error is a "expected primary-expression before ')' token" on the line shown below.

```
float Student::getMark(const string &module) const throw (NoMarkException){ //TODO
    map<string, float>::iterator p;
    p = marks.find(module); //no match for operator=
    if(p != marks.end())
        return p->second;
    else
        throw (NoMarkException); //expected primary-expression before ')' token
    return 0.0; 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your member function is marked `const`.  That means all members you access in the function are also `const` qualified.  This means when you call `find` it returns a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`.  You can fix it by using

```
map<string, float>::const_iterator p;
```

Or even easier with

```
auto p = marks.find(module);
```

As far as your error with throwing the exception you should be creating a object to throw.  That means you need throw `throw NoMarkException();` not `throw (NoMarkException);`